# How to prevent inner html elements from capturing JavaScript events?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

On my computer, the described issue only happens in Chrome and Opera (and not in IE or Firefox). But I think it is related rather to JavaScript than to any specific browser.

Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/JN37b/

html:

```
<ul>
    <li>one</li>
    <li>two</li>
    <li>three</li>
</ul>
```

JavaScript:

```
$('ul').mouseout(function() {
    event.stopPropagation(); //this just for testing
    alert('out');
});
```

and some CSS..

It looks like this:

[image]

When you hover the mouse (in Chrome or Opera) over the red block (which is `<ul>`), and move the mouse horizontally over the smaller blue boxes (which are `<li>`), then the alert box appears. This means that the `mouseout` event was fired on the `<ul>` element.

Question: how to prevent the `<li>` from capturing the mouse, make them transparent for this event, so that the `mouseout` event only happens when the mouse completely leaves the `<ul>` area?

I tried `event.stopPropagation();` but it is useless, because it works in the opposite direction.

Comment: check out http://www.mkyong.com/jquery/different-between-mouseout-and-mouseleave-in-jquery/ to get understand the difference between `mouseout` and `mouseleave` event

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using the mouseleave event instead

```
$('ul').mouseleave(function() {
    alert('out');
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/JN37b/3/)